# Ambiguous Swift initializers when optional arguments can have different types

Tags: swift

Right now I'm working with a class that has a lot of optional properties. For a couple of those optional properties, I want to be able to take in different types, and basically convert them under the hood to the type I want to store it as, for the user's convenience. For example, the user could supply a `Date`, a `String` or an `Int` to indicate a certain date. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. (Ignore the fact that I'm doing a potentially unsafe wrapping.)

```
class SOExample {
    let value: Int
    let time: Double?

    init(value: Int, time: Double? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.time = time
    }

    convenience init(value: Int, time: Int? = nil) {
        if time != nil {
            self.init(value: value, time: Double(time!))
        } else {
            self.init(value: value, time: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to initialize without any optionals - it doesn't know what initializer to use. For example, `SOExample(value: 7)` gives this back in a unit test:

```
error: ambiguous use of 'init(value:time:)'
        let soExample = SOExample(value: 7)
                        ^
<unknown>:0: note: found this candidate
<unknown>:0: note: found this candidate
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
```

How would I be able to do what I'm trying to do? Am I going about this the completely wrong way? Should I be using something other than multiple initializers to do this?

Comment: can you just remove the unwanted parameter from one of the inits ?

Comment: Can you show an example that makes more sense? Your code crashes because you unwrap a `nil` value and `fooDouble: Int` is obvious non-sense.

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin that did do the trick! Now I feel silly for asking this. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Hamish fixed the boneheaded example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Eugene Zhenya Gordin, this issue can be solved by eliminating the optional component on the `convenience init` initializer. If we only want that initializer to be called when the `time` parameter is an `Int`, then it makes sense that the variable should become required for that particular `init`. This resolves the ambiguity in this case.

```
class SOExample {
    let value: Int
    let time: Double?

    init(value: Int, time: Double? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.time = time
    }

    convenience init(value: Int, time: Int) {
        self.init(value: value, time: Double(time))
    }
}
```

This doesn't let me use `Int?` as the parameter type, though, because ultimately that looks like an unresolvable ambiguity. Might as well force it, since that works well enough for my application anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the issue by removing unwanted parameter in one of your init functions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve your issue would be to rename the second parameter in your convenience method. The signatures of the the two initializer methods is the same when you pass nil in which causes your issue. I am not sure if this would work your case.

```
class SOExample {
let value: Int
let time: Double?

init(value: Int, time: Double? = nil) {
    self.value = value
    self.time = time
}

convenience init(value: Int, timeAsInt: Int? = nil) {
    if timeAsInt != nil {
        self.init(value: value, time: Double(timeAsInt!))
    } else {
        self.init(value: value, time: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Given that the signatures of the the two methods are the same and you cannot use the same labels for the second parameter with different types and a default value of nil you could create a static method for your class that will take in a type of `Any` and then work through the possible cases.

```
    class SOExample {
    let value: Int
    let time: Double?




    init(value: Int, time: Double? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.time = time
    }

    static func make(value: Int, time: Any? = nil) -> SOExample {

        if time != nil {

            // Int
            if let timeInt = time as? Int {
                return SOExample(value: value, time: Double(timeInt))
            }

            // String
            if let timeString = time as? String {
                if let timeDouble = Double(timeString) {
                    return SOExample(value: value, time: timeDouble)
                }
            }
        }

        return SOExample(value: value)
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
let exampleOne = SOExample.make(value: 4, time: 4)
let exampleTwo = SOExample.make(value: 4, time: "4")
```